# Zend error trying to log into admin when switching from shared hosting to VPS hosting

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, ce-1.9.2.0

Since I moved from a shared hosting to a VPS hosting plan to get a lot more memory for my website, I have had an issue where i'm completely unable to login to the admin of magento.

I'm completely unable to do anything with my website, I was wondering if anyone knows what would cause this and how I can fix it?

I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column `` 'SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(ma' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) * main_table`.`base_to_global_rate)` AS `lifetime`, `AVG((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) * main_table`.`base_to_global_rate)` AS `average` FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.status NOT IN('canceled')) AND (main_table.state NOT IN('new', 'pending_payment')) ``

Trace:

```
Trace:
#0 includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 includes/src/__default.php(65491): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 includes/src/__default.php(54710): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 includes/src/__default.php(55747): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#4 includes/src/__default.php(56683): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#5 includes/src/__default.php(54967): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#6 includes/src/__default.php(32325): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#7 includes/src/__default.php(32951): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#8 includes/src/__default.php(32157): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales.php(65): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales->_prepareLayout()
#11 includes/src/__default.php(28460): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#12 includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard.php(54): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#13 includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#14 includes/src/__default.php(28460): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#15 includes/src/__default.php(28476): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#16 includes/src/__default.php(28243): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#17 includes/src/__default.php(28209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 includes/src/__default.php(28214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 includes/src/__default.php(14198): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#20 includes/src/__default.php(14123): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#21 includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#23 includes/src/__default.php(14272): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#24 includes/src/__default.php(18726): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#25 includes/src/__default.php(18256): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 includes/src/__default.php(21084): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}
```

The error and trace can also be seen here on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/V9Htwmfj

Comment: I see by the trace that you have the compiler turned on. Try turning it off and see if this still happens

Comment: Any way to do this without logging in to magento admin?

Answer (score 3):

I reckon you should disable the compilation first. You can do it without the admin by following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi

Once you're done log back in to your admin, flush the cache and recompile should fix your problem.

Comment: Haha, I was just about to comment that same SO answer of Alan Storm ;)

Comment: Yeah his explanations are always clear and provides deep details about our Magento works.